# ImageIcon (GIF) To Byte Array

Tags: java, inputstream, gif, discord4j

I'm currently working on a bot project for a Discord server with different activities. Now, I want the bot to be able to send gifs, but as far as I have explored in the Discord4j API you need to send it as an `InputStream`.

`ImageIO.write` method doesn't support gifs but `ImageIcon` does and that's why I can't use the `ImageIO.write` to write to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Do I have to stick to sending static photos or is there another way? Or is the solution to use another API?

Here's how the method looks right now:

```
public final static void sendPicture(final BufferedImage image, final MessageChannel channel) throws IOException
{
    final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "gif", outputStream);
    final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

    System.out.println("Sending picture...");
    channel.createMessage(messageCreateSpec -> {
        messageCreateSpec.addFile("output.gif", inputStream);
    }).block();

    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that at some point, the `ImageIcon` was created from a reference to the gif itself?  Why not use it directly instead?  I'm assuming you're trying to write an animated gif?

Comment: I want to write an animated gif yes, but i can only send it to the message channel through a InputStream. So right now I'm using image.io to get the gif from an url.

Comment: Ok, so, read the gif from the URL and pipe it through the channel's stream - you don't need `BufferedImage`.  `ImageIO.write` is just going to return the encoded image information (ie, png) anyway, so it's basically the same thing

Comment: I read the gif from the url with the ImageIcon(). But I cant pass it through the addfile method because it takes a string and an InputStream. Or did I missunderstand your comment? And the ImageIO.write doesn't take an ImageIcon as a parameter

Comment: So [`URL`] has a `openStream` method, which returns .... `InputStream` .  See [`URL#openStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()) for more details.  So, now you have an instance of `InputStream`, you could just pipe it directly to your output

Comment: How cool! I didn't know you could convert a url to a inputstream. I need to research more about that thanks alot and for the lightning quick answer!

Comment: And if I had it stored locally I would just use the FileInputStream, You learn new things everyday :D

Comment: No worries, I probably would have run around in circles trying to convert a gif to `BufferedImage` and write it it to :P

Comment: I just did that before posting here. I tried `new ImageIcon("URL").getImage().getGraphics().drawBytes()` and thought that the method where gonna write the bytes from the graphics object onto the byte array. But than I read what the method actually does and I got a hard laugh out of it.